# Click two links with one click

Tags: jquery, bind

I am trying to write some jquery that will allow me to click two links at the same time. I want to click #campaign and #link32 at the same time. So far I have this code...

```
$('#campaign').bind('click', function() {
    #link32);
});
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Im sure I am just messing up something simple. Can anyone help.

Thanks,

Nate

Comment: Well you haven't explained in what way it "doesn't seem to be working." Nor have you provided a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can try and see what's going on. You've also not provided your HTML, so we can't work out if you've got a typo with your `id`s. Plus it *should* [work, since this does] (http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PuVav/) (Windows XP/Chrome 18).

Comment: Do you really want to click 2 different links or have 1 click() event that will fire when either of the two links are clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use trigger() method:>
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
  $('#campaign').click( function() {
        $("#link32").trigger("click");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#campaign").click(function() {
  $("#link32").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the theoretical answer:

```
$('#campaign').bind('click', function() {
    $('#link32').click();
});
```

Though most browsers block this kind of activity intentionally as a security precaution. What does link32 do? Have its functions run as JS as part of #campaign's function.

Comment: That is, if they are both navigational links, I should clarify

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open 2 URLs at once, I would build a function to open 2 URLs, rather than trying to click on them.